# Reading inputs from HTML forms

Tags: html, forms

When I found that I could clear a search box like this:

```
<input type='text' name='search' value='Search Here' onfocus='if (this.value == "Search Here")this.value = ""' />
```

It brought up two questions.

1) what language is this in? Are if statments built with HTML or javascript?

2) is there a way for a text input to mirror the value of another? (maybe value='id.value';)

Comment: 1. JavaScript, yes. 2. Yes by using JavaScript `document.getElementById('textinput1').value = document.getElementById('textinput2').value;` replace textinput1's value with textinput2's

Comment: I was trying your code and it wasnt working, then I realized I was doing two.value = one.value (coping two to one (empty to typed)) then I realized it would only update onblur so I had to call the script on keydown

Answer (score 3):

The language you are seeing is inline javascript, considered deprecated. It is better to have the handler inside a script.

If you need a refresher on javascript, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Comment: I guess I don't know Javascript. I hate it, so I never learned it. Now after a few years of web design, I am seeing more and more of a use for it.

Answer (score 0):

That language is called **drums** [javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). If you don't know, I'd suggest you take a look at [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page), a javascript library that simplifies a bunch of tasks.

You can do many other things not just mirror values. You can add new elements, move old elements, get off-page data.

What can I say? Welcome to web development.

Comment: I thought jQuery was part of AJAX

Comment: @jacob jQuery is build on top of JavaScript. it's just another JavaScript Framework

Comment: @jacob NooooOoooooo. jQuery is a javascript LIBRARY! Much like Prototype or Dojo. AJAX is a collection of techniques that in 9 out of 10 cases uses javascript to function.